# Voltage output for a load of 0.8 amps

Tags: voltage-regulator

What will the output voltage be for the given voltage regulator, if the input voltage is 12v and the load is 0.8 amps.

https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_51262_-1

I can't make heads or tails of the datasheet in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

The output voltage will be 5V +/- 2%. This seems to be pretty clear from the brief specifications on the Jameco page. However, the regulator will be dissipating (12V-5V)*0.8A = 5.6W and you are going to need a good heatsink to keep the regulator from overheating.

Comment: While it's rated for 5v, I was under the impression that linear voltage regulators dropped voltage as the load increased.

Comment: @KevinSoviero - it wouldn't be a very good voltage regulator if the output voltage varied significantly with load.

Comment: The load regulation for the 7805 appears to be a maximum of 50mV and typically much less than that. So, I guess you could say that the output voltage is +2%, -3%.

Comment: I would say, it will be 6mV lower than on 0A output current: 8mOhm output impedance x 0.8A output current. This +-2% is about other properties.

Comment: @johnfound You are extrapolating from "typical" specifications which is always dangerous. The data sheet clearly specifies the worst-case load regulation, for junction temperature up to 125C and loads up to 1A, to be 50mV. If you really want your design to work, use the worst case specifications.